# Not able to stop the SMB1 Service

Tags: powershell, smb

In my Windows Server 2008 R2 both SMB1 and SMB2 are present. I want to disable SMB1. I am using the following PowerShell commands to disable SMB1 service:

```
sc.exe config lanmanworkstation depend= bowser/mrxsmb20/nsi
sc.exe config mrxsmb10 start= disabled
stop-service mrxsmb10
```

But, I get the following error when I run the last command :

```
Stop-Service mrxsmb10
```

```
Stop-Service : Service 'SMB 1.x MiniRedirector (mrxsmb10)' cannot be stopped due
to the following error: Cannot stop mrxsmb10 service on computer '.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Stop-Service mrxsmb10
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Stop-Service],    ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStopService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopServiceCommand
```

Someone please tell me what can be the possible root cause for this.
How can I solve this?

Comment: are there any dependencies on this service? what happens when You use stop-service -force? 
in worst case - You can find the exact process running this service and kill it :)

Comment: @Tomek when I use the command stop-service mrxsmb10 -force, I get the same error as mentioned

Comment: and if You use sc.exe stop mrxsmb10 ? does 
stop-service mrxsmb10 -verbose produce any additional info? 
maybe process running the service is hung in some wierd way and does not accept stop command ?

Comment: @Tomek When I ran the command sc.exe stop mrxsmb10, I got the following output- The requested control is not valid for this service. And when I ran the command stop-service mrxsmb10 -verbose, I got the following error - VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Stop-Service" on target "SMB 1.x MiniRedirector (mrxsmb10)". Followed by earlier mentioned error

Comment: https://firewallengineer.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/how-to-stop-not_stoppable-windows-services-via-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to disable SMBv1, you would be best to follow the instructions within this article

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and

Please ensure that you read the article thoroughly as there are consequences to disabling when using Windows 2008 R2

Hope that helps.

Comment: The article talks about the same commands which I have mentioned in my query. The last command stop-service mrxsmb10 does not stop the service. I want to know the way to stop it.

Comment: Silly question but have you changed the relevant Registry Keys and restarted the server?